# MotionEye on Pi Zero Not Identifying Additional Storage Space After Image Flash to Larger SD Card

Tags: motion

Been setting up a Pi Zero with the latest Raspbian and Motioneye 4.2.2.

After setting things up, I needed extra space to store videos.

Got a new larger SD card and flashed the existing image (with Motioneye installed) to the new larger SD card.

Unforunately, Motioneye still thinks I have the same amount of space and isn't storing any more files than the original size of the old SD card.

Do I have to re-install Motioneye for it to see the new space?

-DP

raspberry-pi
motioneyeos

Comment: Have you expanded the filesystem to use all the space? There's an option in `sudo raspi-config` to do that.

Comment: That did the trick man. First flash of an existing image to a new card and didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 2):

After you clone an SDCard from a small one to a large one (depending how you do the cloning) then the new filesystem may be left the same size as the original card (with a lot of unused/unallocated space behind it).

RaspioOS includes two tools that can help avoid that.

1. The SD Card Copier which first formats the new card to the maximum available size then does a file by file copy of the original card.
2. Raspi-config includes a function to expand the file system to the full size of the SDCard. On the first boot after copying an image file to the SDCard that will be run automatically. On a card that's been cloned without using the SD Card Copier you need to run that manually.